# What is the notation $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm familiar with $M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ being the set of all $m\times n$ matrices, but I'm not sure I know what this one is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually denotes the set of all $n\times n$ real matrices.